# Angular 6 and spring boot remember me with session based login

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

Currently, In our spring boot application, we are authenticating users based on HeaderHttpSessionStrategy which is session based authentication. Trying to add remember me functionality, but spring is not storing users into persistent_logins either cookie also not created client side.

I have added

```
//this line added to HttpSecurity object 
.and().rememberMe().rememberMeParameter("rememberMe")
.tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository())
.tokenValiditySeconds(86400)

@Bean
public DataSource getDataSource() {
    DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("${db.driver}");
    dataSourceBuilder.url("${db.url}");
    dataSourceBuilder.username("${db.username}");
    dataSourceBuilder.password("${db.password}");
    return dataSourceBuilder.build();
}

@Bean
public PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository() {
    JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl jdbcTokenRepository = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
    jdbcTokenRepository.setDataSource(getDataSource());
    return jdbcTokenRepository;
}
```

We are using Angular 6 as Front end client, So sending rememberMe header in Post method of an authentication endpoint.

Please suggest someone what I am missing here.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

After so much digging into remember-me authentication, I am able to achieve the functionality.
credit must go to the author of this [link](http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.com/2014/03/securing-your-mobile-api-spring-security.html)

This link alone is enough for the backend part.

When it comes to angular 6, read the response as ResponseEntity so it will automatically create a cookie for you. (If in case you have data to receive from auth endpoint then add them to response header, read them in component as `data.headers.get('some_header_from_api')`)

```
  getToken(username:string,password:string,rememberMe:string){
     let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
       'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
       'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
       'Authorization': 'Basic '+ btoa(username +':'+ password),

     });
     return this.http.get<HttpResponse<Object>>(this.BASE_URL+"?rememberMeChecked="+rememberMe,{ headers: httpHeaders,withCredentials: true,observe: 'response'});
   }
```

Thats it. Wait if you are thinking of how to send a remember-me cookie in each request, actually, you don't need to do any additional work, angular automatically adds cookies for you.